# javascript canvas putImageData not writing modified data

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm attempting to desaturate an image. I'm currently loading it, parsing the image data, but I can't get it to write back to the canvas.

I've followed all of the directions to do

```
context.putImageData(imagedata,0,0);
```

I do this, but the image data doesn't change. "ctx" is the context of the image that is previously loaded that is being turned greyscale.

```
    greyscale: function grayscale(ctx){

        var id = ctx.getImageData(0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

        for(var i=0; i<id.height; i++){
            for(var e=0; i<id.width; i++){

                var index = (e*4)*id.width+(i*4);

                var avg = (id.data[index] + id.data[index+1] + id.data[index+2]) / 3

                id.data[index] = avg;     
                id.data[index+1] = avg;
                id.data[index+2] = avg;
            }
        }

        ctx.putImageData(id,0,0);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop is comparing and incrementing i instead of e.

You also have e and i switched when you calculate the index. It should be (with the 4 factored out):

```
var index = 4 * (i*id.width + e);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer you seek, but have you looked at flot.js?  Nice charting features and the source code is available for perusal.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here :

```
for(var e=0; i<id.width; i++){
```

your "e" is not rise up